# Hover dropdown triangle does not appear in Xcode 10

Tags: xcode, dropdown, xcode10

When I click a variable in Xcode 10 editor and hover the mouse over it, it does not show me the dropdown triangle like this:

[image: Dropdown Triangle]

The triangle allows to choose options on that variable like "Edit all in Scope" etc.

Did I set something in Xcode that disabled those inference cues?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think your project is indexing is not completed. Try again or Quit xcode and relaunch and check now

Comment: hi thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately it did not work for me.  I even uninstalled/re-installed Xcode 10, rebooted my Mac, created a brand new project, added a var, still no hover triangle.  I must have changed some Preferences setting but can't figure out where.

Comment: Check you ios sdk path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That arrow is **no longer available** in Xcode 10. To achieve the same functionality, CMD+click on a variable/function/etc., which will bring up this popup menu:

[image: popup menu appearing after CMD+clicking]

Comment: Thank you! that must be it.  i tried many tricks, reinstalled Xcode, deleted configurations, changed themes,etc.  I also read and searched the Xcode 10 Release Notes but did not find any reference to it being removed.  May be I didn't know how to look.